# How to insert fetch array properly

Tags: arrays, fetch

How could I insert a fetch array into this code. I don't get fetcharray.

```
$ctext = "SELECT tekst FROM members"; 

if (mysqli_query($conn, $ctext))
    {
        echo $ctext;
    }
    else
    {
    echo "erooroorror"; 
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ctext = "SELECT tekst FROM members"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $ctext);
if ($result) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['tekst'] . '<br />';
    }
} else {
    echo "erooroorror"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can insert it by performing batch operation. please check below code, hope it will help you to find the solution

```
  $QueryToMember = mysql_query("SELECT tekst FROM members");

 if ($QueryToMember) {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($QueryToMember)) {
        $Array[] = "('" . $row['tekst'] . "')";
       }

       if (isset($Array) && count($Array) > 0) {

           $InsertString = implode(',', $Array);

    $Query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test1 (tekst) VALUES " . $InsertString);
        }
    } 
    else {
       echo "erooroorror";
    }
```